Upsampling realtime data for sensor fusion
I am doing a real-time sensor fusion of gps and imu streams using a Kalman filter. Both streams are obtained independently (with geolocation and accl-gyro values) in real time. I am doing this in python.
The issue is the sampling rate of IMU stream is about 10-100 times higher than the GPS stream. For sensor fusion, i need both the data at every step (imu for the predict and gps for update at every step of the Kalman filter) . What would be the best way to solve this, upsampling the GPS or downsampling the IMU or going somewhere in between?
In any case, give a proper solution on how to do this while handling realtime data and provide techniques for upsampling or downsampling.
thanks :)

How are you implementing the sensor fusion?  A Kalman filter? Why do you feel you need the sampling rates to match? Please edit your question with any relevant new information.
